# What does "翻起了短信" mean?

Tags: translation

> xxx翻起了短信

I know that 翻 can mean flp, cross, etc. So does the phrase mean "flipping through messages" or "crossing through messages", aka "deleting messages"? Could it also mean "replying to messages"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filpping through text messages.

Comment: cf。iciba： 2. He flipped through the post without opening any of it. 他飞快地翻了一下邮件，但一封也没有打开。
 7. He thumbed through a couple of pages, feigning just a slight interest.他随手翻了几页，假装兴趣不大。

also according to e。g。外国人实用汉语语法，the verbs 上，下进，出，回，过 and 起 as complement indicate the actual direction of a motion in relation to a place。
3. The tractor churn ed up the soil.拖拉机翻起土坡.